# Cache issue in Yii

Tags: caching, yii, size, memcached

I am using `Yii v. 1.1.14` to cache some data using `CMemCache`:

```
    $realtyJsonCacheId = 'realtyForMap';
    $realtyJson = Yii::app()->cache->get($realtyJsonCacheId);
    if ( $realtyJson === false )
    {
        $realty = Realty::model()->findAll();
        $realtyJson = CJSON::encode($realty);
        $realtyJsonDep = new CDbCacheDependency("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Realty");
        Yii::app()->cache->set($realtyJsonCacheId,$realtyJson,0,$realtyJsonDep);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "CACHED";
    }
```

The problem is that the size of data I am trying to cache is over 2Mb and it actually gets cached, when it should not be.

My `memcached` server is default counfigured, I launch it using `sudo service memcached -I 1M` command.

I would like to know what and why is going on. Obviously the data IS being cached, but why and how?

Comment: you want to know why it's being cached??

Comment: @tinybyte yes that is what I want to know. The memcached server is configured to cache only 1Mb of data, but when I try to cache 2Mb it gets cached.